# How to list only the name of the baselines in UCM ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool, baseline

If I do:

```
cleartool lsbl -stream stream:mystream@\mypvob
```

That will lists the baselines with details.
But I want to list only the name of the baselines.

Is there anyway I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`fmt_ccase` options](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) in order to format the result of a [`cleartool lsbl` command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsbl.htm).

```
cleartool lsbl -fmt "%n\n" -stream stream:mystream@\mypvob
```

Comment: is there any easy way to get only manual baselines not the auto baseline(auto generated by ClearCase)?

Comment: @knm: yes, add `%[label_status]p` to the `-fmt` directive, and exclude 'unlabeled' from the result: `cleartool lsbl -fmt "%n %[label_status]p\n" -stream stream:mystream@\mypvob | grep -vi unlabeled`

Answer (score 4):

Here two examples in python, found on [snip2code.com](http://www.snip2code.com)

1) Get the foundation baseline of a stream

```
import os
working_stream = "myStream"
pvob = "MyVobs"
foundation_bl = os.popen("cleartool descr -fmt \"%[found_bls]CXp\" stream:"
    + working_stream + "@" + pvob).readlines()[0].split(":")[1].split("@")[0]
print "Found Foundation baseline = " + str(foundation_bl)
```

Link: [How To Get The Foundation Baseline](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/11386/How-to-get-the-foundation-baseline-of-a-?fromPage=1)

2) Get all baselines of a stream

```
import os
stream = "myStream@/myVobs"
latest_bl=os.popen("for a in `cleartool lsstream -fmt \"%[latest_bls]p\" " + 
               stream + "`; do echo $a; done").readlines()
print "Latest baseline found = " + str(latest_bl)
```

Link: [How To Get The Baselines From UCM Stream](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/11385/How-to-get-the-baselines-from-UCM-stream?fromPage=1)

Comment: That seems very powerful, also applied to a set of other scenarios