# Find UCM baseline history

Tags: cleartool

We have used 'cleartool lsbl -fmt ...' to get baselines on our stream. We could use other ccase_fmt targets, but we want more than just the latest/most recent, and we have no need for the foundation baselines.

I would like to use 'cleartool find  -kind baseline -version "{created_since(...)}" ...' to extract the most recent baselines and then do post-processing as retrieving all of them via 'cleartool lsbl -fmt ...' is taking progressively longer as the projects proceed.

How can I tell 'cleartool find' to give me all baselines on a given stream since time_t?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to list all baselines on a stream (as I did in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19288635/6309)):

```
cleartool lsbl -fmt "%n %d\n" -stream stream:mystream@\mypvob
```

They are sorted from the oldest to the newest, as I mentioned in "[cleartool: How to list all labels in a stream chronologically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13036581/6309)".

(you can limit that for a given component, [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19394872/6309))